# Is piano a percussion instrument

Tags: piano

Could the piano be considered a percussion instrument as it has hammers hitting on suspended strings? Just an interesting thought...

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  When used as an orchestral instrument - as part of the orchestra rather than as a solo - then it is normally regarded as part of the percussion section.

Comment: Dupe - 'Strings versus percussion - what is a piano'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sometimes it's useful to recognise the percussive element of the piano.

But we mustn't get too hung up on classification.  Piano has strings, which are played (sort of) percussively, but doesn't fit either the 'stringed instruments' or 'percussion instrument' category very well.  Likewise organ and 'wind instrument'.   Recognise these aspects, and don't lose sleep over which pigeon-hole they go in!

Comment: Nice, I like your answer! Don't lose sleep over which pigeon hole they go in! Brilliant.

Comment: Indeed.  Classifications are a useful shorthand but don't necessarily cut nature at the joints (as Plato thought they did).  Guitars and even flutes are also "percussive" to some extent.